# Laravel validation rules for array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I actually need to do a validation, which needs to check for a filed which is

1. Required
2. Array
3. Needs to have at least two columns
4. One key name should be `correct_topic`
5. Other one needs to be `wrong_topic`

Now I am writing the rules like the following for other fields.

```
return [
         'category'   => 'required|numeric',
         'text' => 'required',
         'type' => 'required|numeric|in:1,2,3',
         'vendor'        => 'required|numeric|exists:users,id',
         'topic' => 'required|array'
       ];
```

How can I improve this and include the above mentioned validation for `topic` ?

I am writing these rules in a `TopicRequest` class. Basically I need to check whether the filed `topic` is an array which has got at least 2 columns and not more than 4 and one of the array key should be `correct-topic` and others needs to be `wrong_topic_1` etc.

Is there any default validation rules that can be used effectively for this situation ?

Comment: Not clear the issue

Comment: you have to write custom validation rule for topic .

Comment: Any example of the inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validator.[Laravel Valditation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly fulfill above validation lists with first `array` validation and using `dot notation` validation style like the below:

```
return [
    ................
     'topic' => 'required|array|min:2|max:4',
     'topic.correct_topic' => 'required',
     'topic.wrong_topic' => 'required'
];
```

Using the min and max according to the Laravel doc, uses [the size rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-size) with on an files fields which *I believe should also be relevant for arrays*, i.e employs the `count()` method. Ref [min-here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-min) and [max-here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-max)

> PS: I can't be sure this really fix your issue particularly but I believe it should give an inspiration to the answer you need.

You can also refer to [Validating Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays) if any doubts

Hope it helps :)